# Ignore loading eager one-to-one hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have a ProductGroup, Product and DetailProduct with the following:

```
class ProductGroup {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productGroup", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST], orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    open var product: MutableList<Product> = mutableListOf()
}

class Product {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST])
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PRODUCT_GROUP", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    open var productGroup: ProductGroup? = null,

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST], mappedBy = "product", optional = false, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    open var detailProduct: DetailProduct? = null
}

class DetailProduct {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST])
    @MapsId("ID_PRODUCT")
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PRODUCT", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    var product: Product? = null,

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @MapsId("ID_CODE_PRODUCT")
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CODE_PRODUCT", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    var codeProduct: CodeProduct? = null
}
class CodeProduct {
    //Properties
}
```

When i get list `ProductGroup`, i only want get list `Product` with `DetailProduct`, without `CodeProduct`, but it still call query get `CodeProduct`. It seems `DetailProduct` loading eager CodeProduct. Although i set `FetchType.LAZY`. That makes the query very long.

How can fix it?
Thank guys!

Answer (score 1):

This is simply how one-to-one mappings work. Hibernate has to initialize the `codeProduct` field to some value. Since your mapping uses the primary key `ID_CODE_PRODUCT` as join column which is never null Hibernate must query the database to see if the object actually exists, so it can decide whether to set `null` or a proxy. You could theoretically use a `@ManyToOne` instead, which will then avoid querying but always set a proxy. Accessing that proxy might produce an exception then though when Hibernate figures out the object does not exist during lazy loading.

I would recommend you you to not use entities in this case, but create a dedicated DTO.

You might like what [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) has to offer.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(ProductGroup.class)
public interface ProductGroupDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    List<ProductDto> getProduct();
}
@EntityView(Product.class)
public interface ProductDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    DetailProductDto getDetailProduct();
}
@EntityView(DetailProduct.class)
public interface DetailProductDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    String getName();
    // Other fields you need form the product
}
```

Or if you want to flatten this a bit, like this:

```
@EntityView(ProductGroup.class)
public interface ProductGroupDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    List<ProductDto> getProduct();
}
@EntityView(Product.class)
public interface ProductDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    @Mapping("detailProduct.name")
    String getName();
    // Other fields you need form the product
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ProductGroupDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ProductGroupDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

You could use the Spring Data naming convention to construct the query which would look roughly like this:

```
List<ProductGroupDto> findAll();
```